# For which values of $\beta > 0$ is the function $f(x,y)=(x^3+y^5-5xy)(x^2+y^2)^{-\beta}$ continuous at the origin?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Given the function
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
(x^3+y^5-5xy)(x^2+y^2)^{-\beta}, &(x,y) \neq (0,0)\\
0, & (x,y) = (0,0).
\end{cases}$$
and $\beta > 0$,

determine for which values of $\beta$ the function is continuous at the origin.

My try involves rewriting the function in polar form, $x = r \cos t, y = r \sin t$:

$$(r^3\cos^3t + r^5\sin^5 t - 5 r^2 \sin t \cos t)(r^2)^{-\beta} = r^{2-2\beta}(r \cos^3 t + r^3 \sin^5 t - 5 \sin t \cos t)$$

For $r \to 0$ the only terms still left will be

$$r^{2-2\beta}(- 5 \sin t \cos t)$$

I am unsure about how to continue. I see that $\beta =1$ makes the first factor equal to 1, and the ? I feel like I am on the edge of finding out the answer, but how can I motivate it for *every* value of $\beta\mkern 1.5mu$?

Comment: Are you asking two questions? The question in the title is different from the other one.

Comment: I could not fit the whole equation with cases etc. in the title, thought it might be helpful to see at least part of it.

Comment: You have $y^{3}$ in the title and $y^{5}$ in the question. Why $f(x,y)$ in the title and $g(x,y)$ later? It looks as though you have two different questions.

Comment: My mistake! The errors are now adjusted, thank you for pointing them out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both questions (Title & Body) you have term $-5xy$ in nominator that has the least degree ($2$ in total from both $x,y$). Since you goes to origin the least power only stay in limit. so it's equals to:
$$Limit \ at \ Origin = \lim_{(x,y) \longmapsto (0,0)} \frac{-5xy}{(x^2+y^2)^{\beta}}$$
So in denominator degree of both variaibles is $2\beta$, and nominator degree for each variables is $1$. If we want to limit goes to $0$, so we must have:
$$2\beta<1 \Longrightarrow \beta<\frac{1}{2} \Longrightarrow 0<\beta<\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

$$\bigl|r^{2-2\beta}(- 5 \sin t \cos t)\bigr|\le 5\mkern1.5mu r^{2-2\beta}.$$